# How can I manually fail a package in Integration Services?

Tags: ssis

I am running an Execute SQL Task statement in my SSIS package. The Execute SQL Task is running sql and checking that the tables have more than 1000 rows. If they have less than 1000 rows, I want to fail the package.

How do I force a fail inside of a SQL statement?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

AFAIK, tasks in SSIS fail on error. So if your Execute SQL Task has a statment like so in it:

```
declare @count int
select @count = select count(*) from my_table
if @count < 1000
begin
    raiserror('Too few rows in my_table',16,1)
end
else
begin
    -- Process your table here
end
```

You should get the results you want.

Comment: You would also have to set the package properties correctly, and possibly set 'failparentonerror'

Comment: raiserror('Too few rows in my_table',16,1)


That does the trick!  I guess it wasn't so much of an SSIS question and more of a SQL question.  Thanks.

Comment: Note that the error needs to be a high enough level, for example `raiserror('Too few rows in my_table',1,1)` wouldn't work

Answer (score 21):

I like to force a failure by using a script task. It's really easy.

1) Add the script task

2) Change the line of auto-generated code from :

```
Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
```

to

```
Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Failure;
```

and there you go!

Answer (score 4):

You can create a custom error message like this

```
EXEC sp_ADDMESSAGE 
        @msgnum=55555,
        @severity=1,
        @msgtext='Threshold condition failed. The package execution has been terminated.'
```

You can then call this error using Raiserror()

```
Raiserror (55555,20,-1) WITH LOG
```

You need to enter a number greater than 18 for **severity** (here 20). You need to have admin privileges for this. And dont forget **WITH LOG**

Answer (score 2):

You need to make property FailPackageOnFailure true..try to retrieve the property FailPackageOnFailure  of the particular task and assign the value true. so that package will be failed.

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a user variable. Store the record count in that variable (User::Rcnt)
2. Just use the send mail task and define the work flow.
3. In precedent constraint (User::Rcnt<20)