# Cause SSIS to trigger exception handling process when 0 records have been loaded to a target table

Tags: c#, ssis, visual-studio-2017

I have a requirement to load a text file into a sql server table via SSIS using VS2017. If 0 records were loaded for whatever reason, I need to have the package fail and trigger the exception handling process tied to the package. Is there a clean way to do this? I have it set now to do a select Count(*) on the target table after the load, if the count returned is 0, then I have the process perform another select using an invalid query which causes the package to fail the way I want it to. It seems to me that there should be a better way to do this. Any feedback is appreciated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I manually fail a package in Integration Services?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/435651/how-can-i-manually-fail-a-package-in-integration-services)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few ways to trigger the error event, described here: [How can I manually fail a package in Integration Services?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/435651/how-can-i-manually-fail-a-package-in-integration-services)

Short list:

- use what you have
- use Raiserror in your count(*) query
- use a Script Task to return an error

Comment: @Scratte Ok, flagged it

Comment: Thank you for your help. The raiserror / throw was exactly what I needed.